# kubectl get componentstatus showing extra etcd instances

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, coreos, etcd

I have a single node kubernetes cluster running. Everything working fine, but when I run the "kubectl get cs" (kubectl get componentstatus) it showing two instance of etcd. I have running a single etcd instance.

`[root@master01 vagrant]# kubectl get cs
NAME                 STATUS    MESSAGE              ERROR
controller-manager   Healthy   ok
scheduler            Healthy   ok
etcd-0               Healthy   {"health": "true"}
etcd-1               Healthy   {"health": "true"}`

`[root@master01 vagrant]# etcdctl member list
19ef3eced66f4ae3: name=master01 peerURLs=http://10.0.0.10:2380 clientURLs=http://0.0.0.0:2379 isLeader=true`

`[root@master01 vagrant]# etcdctl cluster-health
member 19ef3eced66f4ae3 is healthy: got healthy result from http://0.0.0.0:2379
cluster is healthy`

Etcd is running as a docker container. In the /etc/systemd/system/etcd.service file single etcd cluster is mentioned.(http://10.0.0.10:2380)

`/usr/local/bin/etcd \
    --name master01 \
    --data-dir /etcd-data \
    --listen-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379 \
    --advertise-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379 \
    --listen-peer-urls http://0.0.0.0:2380 \
    --initial-advertise-peer-urls http://10.0.0.10:2380 \
    --initial-cluster master01=http://10.0.0.10:2380 \
    --initial-cluster-token my-token \
    --initial-cluster-state new \`

Also in the api server config file /etc/kubernetes/manifests/api-srv.yaml --etcd-servers flag is used.

`- --etcd-servers=http://10.0.0.10:2379,`

`[root@master01 manifests]# netstat -ntulp |grep etcd
tcp6       0      0 :::2379                 :::*                    LISTEN      31109/etcd
tcp6       0      0 :::2380                 :::*                    LISTEN      31109/etcd`

Any one know why it showing etcd-0 and etcd-1 in "kubectl get cs" ?. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Provide output for `kubectl get all --all-namespaces -o wide`

Comment: How you created your cluster? Feeling that your cluster looks into the wrong configuration or you had another ETCD prior to installing cluster

Comment: @Jyothish Kumar S did you create the cluster using kops?

Comment: Hi Team,

Thanks for your update @VKR, @David Winder
I think I found the reason. The comma (,) at the end of --etcd-servers=http://10.0.0.10:2379, in the api server config file causing this behavior.
`- --etcd-servers=http://10.0.0.10:2379,`
As far I understand, the comma was adding a new etcd server record with localhost and default port 2379. And it was trying to check the health
on http://:::2379. After removing the comma, "kubectl get cs" showing one etcd instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the fact that @Jyothish Kumar S has found the root cause on his own and fixed the issue - It's a good practice to have an answer that will be available for those, who will face the same problem in the future.

Issue came from missconfiguration in API server config file `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/api-srv.yaml` where`--etcd-servers`  was set in an inappropriate way. 
All flags for `kube-apiserver` along with their descriptions may be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/).
So, the issue was in the last comma in `--etcd-servers=http://10.0.0.10:2379,` line. This comma was interpreted as new ETCD server record `http://:::2379` and that’s why in the `"kubectl get cs"` output we were able to see two etcd records instead of one.
Pay attention to this aspect while configuring etcd.